# Java parsing and extract String from pattern String

Tags: java, parsing, regex

I want to extract some string surrounded by certain patterns.

For Instance, the original String something like `1234@{78}dasdh@{1}fdsfs@{fdf}ad@{`
and I want extract `78`, `1`, `fdf` from it.

Below is my code for the purpose

```
public class Test {

    // want to get "78", "1", "fdf"
    private static String targetStr = "1234@{78}dasdh@{1}fdsfs@{fdf}ad@{";

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> parsed = new ArrayList<>();

        Pattern open = Pattern.compile("@\\{");
        Matcher oMatcher = open.matcher(targetStr);

        Pattern close = Pattern.compile("}");
        Matcher cMatcher = close.matcher(targetStr);

        while(oMatcher.find()) {
            if(cMatcher.find())  parsed.add(targetStr.substring(oMatcher.start() + 2, cMatcher.start()));
        }
        System.out.println(parsed);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to complete this task? Some how it feels unsafe since use 2 iterator without any validation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be solved by looking at the public online documentation.

Comment: _Is there anyway to complete this task?_ You mean any _better_ way to complete this task, right? Or isn't this code working yet?

Comment: @t3chb0t yes. I mistook about the words. Thanks

Comment: @TimothyTruckle It is ok to close, but I would like to know which is the best way to implement that function. In my thought working code and optimized code is different.

Comment: @JuneyoungOh: *"but I would like to know which is the best way to implement that function."* As the answer of *Roland Illig* shows there is a better way and you could have found it your self by reading the free online documentation as I mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simpler way:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+@\\{(\\w+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(targetStr);
while (m.find()) {
    parsed.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Instead of matching the opening and closing braces separately, the above pattern matches a whole expression of the form `aaa@{bbb}` at once. And when it finds the expression, it remembers the part inside the braces. This is done via a *capturing group* (the parentheses).

To learn more about each of the characters in the pattern, read the Javadoc of the Pattern class.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about `group` methods.

Comment: _There's a simpler way:_ - could you add a short description which way and/or why for poeple - like me ;-) who are unable to find the difference?

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks for the suggestion. It reads much better now.